# what is the difference between journey and router in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am confused about journey  and router in node.js. Can any body tell me the exact difference between journey and router in node.js?

Comment: are you asking about https://github.com/cloudhead/journey and routers in general or what? please be more explicit

Comment: exactly. I am not getting the difference as both are used to differentiate between url requests

Answer (score 2):

[Journey](https://github.com/cloudhead/journey) *is* a HTTP request router module for Node.js. It is not a part of the core Node.js. A HTTP request router is a library that facilitates the selection of what code to call, according to the specifics of the HTTP request.